# Is this substitution valid?

Tags: solution-verification, substitution, fake-proofs, euler-mascheroni-constant

So I made this identity for Euler's constant $\gamma$:$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(e^t+t)}tdt=-\gamma$$But this isn't right for some reason. So what's wrong with my proof?:
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\ln tdt=-\gamma$$Make a substitution of $t=\ln u$ to get: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{udu}{e^{e^u}e^u}$$The derivative of $\ln t$ is $\frac{1}{t}$ but our substitution turns it to $\frac{1}{e^t}$. Shouldn't $e^{-t}$ map to $e^{-e^t}$? Where is my mistake?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Please, when you have time, make an answer showing what I did wrong and how to make the answer :)

Comment: please write $ \int_0^\infty e^{-t}\ln tdt $  using $t = e^u,$  so that $\log t = u$  and $dt = e^u du.$ It is very easy to make accounting mistakes; using a new letter   reduces these.

Comment: $$t=\ln(u) \implies \int_0^\infty e^{-t}\ln(t) \, dt = \int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(\ln(u))}{u^2} \, du$$or with $t=-\ln(u)$,$$\int_0^1 \ln(-\ln(u))\,du$$

Comment: If you want this identity, the lower bound of the initial $t$ should be $-1.00905\cdots$